# how to get the city name from shapefiles in java

Tags: java, gis, shapefile

I am having the hard time to understand the concept of shapefiles. I have downloaded the shape file and so far I have understood that I have to dump these file into mysql using some tool like geotool(I am using Java). My doubt is, if I have latitude and longitude , how can i get the city name  in which these lat long falls? I dont want to use google reverse geocoding. 
My knowledge in this area is pretty much limited, so if my question is unclear, do buzz me I will clear it more...
Any link will be helpul..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store some structure to store the range of latitude, longitude a city covers. You can model that as x,y coordinates of rectangle or circle. Then you make a test like

```
if(city.contains(latitude, longitude)
```

Comment: Actually its a otherway around. I want to these rectangle shape ,some how, in mysql  And to to do a query like "select cityName where lat= ** and long =**". Thats why i think that shape files are good for these. i should download them and insert into DB and then i should be able to find out the city name. I am not sure it is possible or not...

Comment: I think it is the same. Once you get the Latitude/Longitude from database, you should check it against another database that contains the gist of latitude/longitude covered by cities. Or, you can calculate the latter on the fly, in case storing latitude/longitude of every city in the planet is too much. I am assuming that, you might use use some library to get world cities along with their latitude/longitude pairs and then say every thing latitude/longitude that lies with in 20 km of radius lies inside the city.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by looking at GeoTools's [Shapefile Datastore](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/data/shapefile/ShapefileDataStore.html) to read and manipulate your dataset.

Now, in order to "get the city name", it's hard to know what you mean unless your provide some information about the data you're using.

Comment: I have some shape files for some of US states , I want to inject them into mysql and when i got anf lat long to search, by using that mysql data I want to find out in which city this lat long falls...appreciate for your patience !